# Prove/Disprove: a function is uniformly continuous

Tags: calculus

> Prove/Disprove: $f(x)$ is defined and second derivative is bounded in $I$, so $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous.

I have started with simple functions like $x^2$ but on a closed interval it is uniformly continuous, moreover, I can not find a connection between derivatives and uniformly continuous

Comment: Any continuous function defined on a closed interval is uniformly continuous.

Comment: What is $I$? any bounded interval ? or is $I$ closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is FALSE if $I$ is not bounded. Take for example $I=\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x)=x^2$. Then $f$ is not uniformly continuous in $I$ but its second derivative is bounded.

It is TRUE if $I$ is a bounded interval.  If the second derivative is bounded in $I$ then also the first derivative is bounded: let $x_0\in I$ then for any $x\in I$, there is $t$ between $x$ and $x_0$ such that
$$f'(x)-f'(x_0)=f''(t)(x-x_0)\Rightarrow |f'(x)|\le |f'(x_0)|+M|I|$$
where $\sup_{x\in I}|f''(x)|=M$ and $|I|$ is the size of $I$.
Hence $f$ is Lipschitz which implies that $f$ is uniformly continuous in $I$.

Answer (score 0):

If just the first derivative is bounded then it is uniformly continuous (think Lipschitz continuity). But the statement is not true (viz. $x^2$ on real line)